# Android: How can I stop an infinite animation applied on an ImageView?

Tags: android, animation, imageview, infinite

I have an ImageView on which I have applied a rotate animation. Since I want the rotation to go on continuously, I gave the repeatCount as infinite in my rotate.xml:

```
android:repeatCount="infinite"
```

In onCreate(), I load the animation and start it.

```
Animation myAnim    = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.rotate);
objectImg.startAnimation(myAnim);
```

When a button is pressed, the rotation must stop. Hence in my onClick(), I called clearAnimation().

```
objectImg.startAnimation(myAnim);
```

My simple question is whether stopping the animation is the right thing to do. 
I assume clearAnimation() corresponds to loadAnimation(), but there is no stopAnimation() that corresponds to startAnimation().

Answer (score 39, accepted):

You can also call `anim.cancel();` but you should also call `anim.reset();` immediately after it.
Then when you want to start it again, just call `startAnimation` on the view.

Comment: animation.cancel(); requires API level 8, for stop the animation in API 7 and above the only option is view.clearAnimation();

Comment: `cancel()` would just reset the whole animation to initial state.  But how to keep the last stopped state?

Comment: Proof of necessity to call anim.cancel() and anim.reset() together.
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/Animation.html#cancel()

Answer (score 75):

Use `clearAnimation()` to stop an animation. There is no `loadAnimation()` on `View`.

Comment: Ok, thanks. So only startAnimation() and clearAnimation() are pplicable to views.

Comment: clearAnimation() didn't work for me, setAnimation(null) did

Comment: Hi @CommonsWare can u tell me how stop animation onClick of the view itself which is animating but not as a separate button?

Comment: `img.clearAnimation()` is the best solution -  `img.setAnimation(null)` also works, but it's less elegant -  `img.startAnimation(null)` causes crash

Comment: I had an infinite animation on an imageView of zoom in/zoom out.
When I was trying to stop animation after clicking on view, neither anim.cancel() nor img.clearAnimation() works for me.
Finally  img.setAnimation(null) worked for me.

Comment: Working perfect

Comment: It's better solution in case if someone doesn't have the access of anim variable

Answer (score -1):

Simply add below two lines.

```
anim?.cancelAnimation()

anim?.progress = 0f
```

Answer (score -1):

You can do it simply by removing this line : `android:repeatCount="infinite"` from your `rotate.xml` file