# How to rotate an image in Android?

Tags: android, animation

How can I rotate an image on android? I am going to use image sequence animation. But I don`t know the java code for that.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
RotateAnimation anim = new RotateAnimation(0, 360,0,0);
anim.setRepeatCount(0);
anim.setDuration(3000);
anim.setFillAfter(true);  
ImageView.startAnimation(anim);
```

Comment: Refer this link to stop animation: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3913750/android-how-to-stop-an-infinite-animation-applied-on-an-imageview